# Find line in file and replace it with line from another file

Tags: awk, sed

My goal is to find a string within a file (file1) and replace its whole line with the content of a specific line (in this example line 3) from another file (file2). As I understand, I need to use RegEx to do the first part and then use a second sed command to store the contents of file2. sed is definitely not my strong suit, so I hope someone here can help a rookie out!

So far I have:

`sed -i '/^matching.string.here*/s' <(sed '3!d' file2) file1`

**Edit**

Example file1:

```
string one
string two
matching.string.here.
string three
```

Example file2:

```
alt string one
alt string two
alt string three
```

Expected Result in file1:

```
string one
string two
alt string three
string three
```

Comment: Can you post some example of data from the two files as well as an extract of your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` attempt contains several unexplained errors; it's actually hard to see what you are in fact trying to do.

You probably want to do something along the lines of

```sh
sed '3!d;s%.*%s/^matching\.string\.here.*/&/%' file2 |
sed -f - -i file1
```

It's unclear what you hope for the `/s` to mean; does your `sed` have a flag with this name?

This creates a `sed` script from the third line of `file2`; take out the pipeline to `sed -f -` to see what the generated script looks like. (If your `sed` does not allow you to pass in a script on standard input, you will have to write it to a temporary file, and then pass that to the second `sed`.)

Anyway, this is probably both simpler and more robust using Awk.

```sh
awk 'NR==3 && NR==FNR { keep=$0; next }
    /^matching\.string\.here/ { $0 = keep } 1' file2 file1
```

This writes the new content to standard output. If you have GNU Awk, you can explore its `-i inplace` option; otherwise, you will need to write the result to a file, then move it back to `file1`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '3s#.*#sed "/matching\\.string\\.here\\./c&" file1#ep' file2
```

Focus on line 3 of file2.

Manufacture a sed script which changes a matching line in file1 to the contents of the line in focus and print the result.

N.B. The periods in the match must be escaped twice so as not to match an arbitrary character.

Answer (score 1):

This is tailor made job for `awk` and bonus is that you can avoid any regex:

```sh
awk -v s='matching.string.here' 'FNR == NR {a[FNR] = $0; next} index($0, s) {$0 = a[FNR]} 1' file2 file1

string one
string two
alt string three
string three
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk -v s='matching.string.here' '
FNR == NR {
   a[FNR] = $0
   next
}
index($0, s) {
   $0 = a[FNR]
} 1' file2 file1
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! However, when I try that it outputs the contents of file1 without any changes. Where exactly does your solution say to use line 3 of file2? Maybe I still just don't get it, sorry.

Comment: This guesses that you want the corresponding line, i.e. if the `matching.string.here` is found on line 2 it would take line 2 from the first input file.

Comment: `$0 = a[FNR]` is the part where it grabs corresponding line no row from `file2` (which is #3 in this case)